# Index of 3 is out of range

Tags: java, sql

I'm new to this forum and also new to SQL.

I've a problem with the below code of mine.

Its throwing an error of `SQLException` which is `the index 3 is out of range`

I don't know what's the problem.

```
public static ArrayList<LotInfoVO> getLotInfoRecords3(String studName,String DoubleCheck, String lngstudid) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        {
            ArrayList <LotInfoVO> lotRecords4 = new ArrayList<LotInfoVO>();
            try {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                PreparedStatement stmt = getCon().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MesLib.tblSchoolRecordsr where strstudName = ? and strDoubleCheckCode = ? and (lngstudID NOT LIKE '-[^0-9]') ");
                stmt.setString(1, studName);
                stmt.setString(2, DoubleCheck);
                stmt.setString(3, lngstudID);

                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()) {
                    LotInfoVO voLotInfo3 = new LotInfoVO();
                    voLotInfo3.setStstudName(rs.getString("strstudName"));
                    voLotInfo3.setLngStudID(rs.getString("lngStudID"));
                    voLotInfo3.setLngStudSubID(rs.getString("lngStudSubID"));
                    voLotInfo3.setStrDoubleCheckCode(rs.getString("strDoubleCheckCode"));
                    voLotInfo3.setStrPackage(rs.getString("strCourse"));
                    voLotInfo3.setStrDimension(rs.getString("strSchool"));
                    voLotInfo3.setStrLead(rs.getString("strSubjects"));
                    //get values for other instance variables
                    lotRecords4.add(voLotInfo3);
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  finally {
                closeConnection();
            }
            return lotRecords4;
        }
    }
```

Sorry for my coding I'm just a new programmer in town..

So please be good to me thanks!

Comment: SQL stands for "structured query language".  Please tell us (update tags) what your DBMS is?  SQL Server?  Oracle?  etc.

Comment: And when you ask about an exception, always post the complete stack trace of the exception. Based on your rephrasing of the message, I suspect the cause is that you set 3 parameters to your statement, although it only has 2 `?`.

Comment: Your query only has two `?` placeholders, not three .

Comment: Count the number of `?` parameter placeholders in your query. then count how many you want to set. The error should be pretty obvious.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... I'm using SQL Server which is new for me. I appreciate your comments but i need the lngStudID so i should put = ? on the last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            PreparedStatement stmt = getCon().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MesLib.tblSchoolRecordsr where strstudName = ? and strDoubleCheckCode = ? and (lngstudID NOT LIKE '-[^0-9]') ");
            stmt.setString(1, studName);
            stmt.setString(2, DoubleCheck);
            stmt.setString(3, lngstudID);
```

Here **two question marks (?)** in your *sql*. So this query wants only two parameter.
But you are setting *three parameters*. Thus **index of 3 out of range** exception occurs.

To avoid this exception remove this line. Cause according to your sql this line (below) is unnecessary

```
            stmt.setString(3, lngstudID);
```

Comment: but i need that lngStudID what should i do with the query?

Answer (score 1):

Just comment this line.

```
stmt.setString(3, lngstudID);
```

The number of  Question marks (?) in the query and supplying parameters should be same.

As you are supplying `lngstudId` as extra you are getting exception.

Comment: i change the (lngstudID NOT LIKE '-[^0-9]') into isNumeric(lngstudID) = 1 but still im getting the same error